# Devexpress WindowsUI document closing

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have been building a winforms windowsui application.I have already created user controls that has controls.when i first click tile item form load event fires,but second click doesnt.
what is the problem.
thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! It is not quite clear to me how the Form.Load event is related to your UserControls. This event occurs only for Forms and only before a form is displayed for the **first time**. Why you are expected that this event will fire when the form is already displayed? Please clarify these points(with some additional details and sample code) to make us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to handle the View's [ControlReleasing event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsBaseView_ControlReleasingtopic) and set the e.KeepControl parameter to false.